# How to write a custom MessageExpectation in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've got a test that I can write using receive() with the block argument to custom validate arguments like this:

```
expect(provider).to receive(:shell_out!) do |*args|
  expect(args.flatten.compact.map(&:to_s)).to eql(["useradd", "-m", "adam"])
end
```

I have hundreds of these tests to write and I'd like to shorten that to:

```
expect(provider).to receive(:shell_out!).with_flat_compact_str("useradd", "-m", "adam")
```

I'm currently heading down the road of monkeypatching in a custom method to implement that into the `RSpec::Mocks::MessageExpectation` class, and I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to get what I want?

Note that the purpose of this is that the `shell_out!(*args)` API will take its splat args and run `args.flatten.compact.map(&:to_s)` over them and I want to allow setting up expectations on the message which won't fail if the caller makes inconsequential changes to the call (i.e. treat `shell_out!(a, b, c)` and `shell_out!(a, nil, [b, c])` as the same.  I also explicitly do not want to call it with one method and then setup an expectation on an internal API call after the splat has been normalized.

Also note that I went down the road of trying to write a custom matcher that looked like this:

```
receive(:shell_out).with(flat_compact_str("useradd", "-m", "adam"))
```

What I found though is that does not work with splat args (at least I couldn't figure it out).  It would work if there was one argument that was an Array, but not across all the args.  Splat arg matchers have special magic in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that subclassing MessageExpectation is probably going to result in pain, the easiest approach is to make a little custom helper method:

```
module ReceiveHelpers
  def receive_with_flat_str(method, *expected)
    receive(method) do |*args|
      expect(args.flatten.compact.map(&:to_s)).to eql(expected)
    end
  end
end

describe ... do
  include ReceiveHelpers

  it do
    expect(Foo).to receive_with_flat_str(:shell_out, "foo", "bar")
  end
end
```

That can either be included in just the example groups that need it, or all groups via the RSpec configuration block.